# PyMongo storing ISODate without milliseconds when milliseconds are zero

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, isodate

After running a script today I noticed that the created_on time for some of my documents looked like:

ISODate("2013-05-30T17:46:55Z") *no millis*

ISODate("2013-05-30T21:08:02.261Z") *millis for most rows*

WHen parsing the former..my code expected the millis to be there:

```
    dt = datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime (data_string, format))
    ValueError: time data '2013-05-30 17:46:55' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

How can I make sure that ISODate("2013-05-30T17:46:55.0000Z") gets stored in the document so that the parser can be consistent?

Answer (score 2):

One option is, store datetimes as datetimes in MongoDB, not as strings. Then you won't need to parse them with `strptime` in order to get datetimes back out and millis are no problem:

```
>>> dt = datetime.now()
>>> str(dt)
'2013-06-03 13:04:22.976182'
>>> db.collection.insert({'now': dt})
ObjectId('51accca7ca1ce90a4277ac20')
>>> dt = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
>>> str(dt)
'2013-06-03 13:04:47'
>>> db.collection.insert({'now': dt})
ObjectId('51acccb6ca1ce90a4277ac21')
>>> pprint.pprint(list(db.collection.find({}, {'now': True, '_id': False})))
[{u'now': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 3, 13, 4, 22, 976000)},
 {u'now': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 3, 13, 4, 47)}]
```

If it's too late for you to change how you store datetimes, you can `pip install python-dateutil` and do:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse('2013-06-03 13:04:22.976182')
datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 3, 13, 4, 22, 976182)
>>> parse('2013-06-03 13:04:22')
datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 3, 13, 4, 22)
```

Comment: use `datetime.utcnow()` instead of `datetime.now()`.